# Mongo Filter Similar Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have this collection:

```
Cards:
[
  {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 1, _id: "c5ea1968-6ab5-4b05-80a9-db9dabe29dde"},
  {orientation: "landscape", size: "45", columns: 3, type: 1, _id: "37186b8e-4033-46c6-8b2e-82ee45f96904"},
  {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 1, _id: "8f49a3ff-2859-4027-b644-88ac0949808d"},
  {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 2, _id: "862717f4-2ef7-4839-947a-02771338c38c"},
  {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 3, _id: "e1a93b10-dfcb-42a2-955a-ee14d539624f"}
]
```

And I need a result like this:

```
CardList:
[
 { type: 1,
   list: [
    {orientation: "landscape", size: "45", columns: 3, type: 1, _id: "1_landscape_2"},
    {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 1, _id: "1_portrait_2"}
   ]
 },
 { type: 2,
   list: [
    {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 2, _id: "2_portrait_2"}
   ],
 { type: 3,
   list: [
    {orientation: "portrait", size: "45", columns: 2, type: 3, _id: "3_portrait_2"}
   ]
 }
];
```

So, group by common attribute **type**, and not repeating documents with same attributes **orientation** and **columns**, for example.

I was able to group by type:

```
{ _id : "$type", list: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
```

But, how would be the next stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `$group` stages like this:

- First group to get the elements where `orientation`, `columns` and `type` are the same. So, that is, create the "list" objects.
- With that objects, another `$group` by the type and add result to an array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "orientation": "$orientation",
        "columns": "$columns",
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "list": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.type",
      "list": {
        "$push": "$list"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_O4IR0AipN6)

Note how the first `$group` uses `$first` to avoid repeated values (each type has one single elements with the same `orientation` and `columns`. And the second `$group` uses `$push` to generate the list.

Also, to get your desired `_id` output (and assuming is compound by `type_orientation_columns`) in the `list` field you can do this:

- Add `orientation` and `columns` in the second `$group` to keep as auxiliar values.
- Use `$project` to get desired values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "orientation": "$orientation",
        "columns": "$columns",
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "list": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.type",
      "list": {
        "$push": "$list"
      },
      "orientation": {
        "$first": "$_id.orientation"
      },
      "columns": {
        "$first": "$_id.columns"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "type": "$_id",
      "list": {
        "orientation": 1,
        "size": 1,
        "columns": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "_id": {
          "$concat": [
            {"$toString": "$_id"},
            "_",
            {"$toString": "$orientation"},
            "_",
            {"$toString": "$columns"}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GqY0uPQBDSF)